# Why software's reverbs algorithms never sound the same as their hardware's original?

Tags: hardware, reverb, plug-ins

I hear hardware units algorithm sounding far better than their software reproduction, more precise, accurate, dense and linear. [listen this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GoO5H_r_8UU)

I know many units run fixed point CPU against the floating present on nowadays computers and it does make difference but I'd like to know in a very technical perspective what are the differences on what's happening and what's algorithmically differs between them.

Comment: The video compares two different algorithms. H8000FW and Blackhole which is supposed to be the same as DSP4000. That's a different unit.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a different algorithm.

Do you think the manufacturers would be able to sell more expensive hardware units if the same algorithms of their boxes in the thousands dollars would be available as $99 plug-ins?

I don't think mere numerics "problems" are able to make substantial changes. It's true that they are related to accuracy, but the numerics "errors" occur in 5 or 6 decimal places and should not affect noticeably if the hardware is designed properly (such errors are like "dither noise" in magnitude). Also, why'd fixed be better than floating point?

Comment: Technically I don't know, I've just being told that on some hardware units is running a fixed point CPU, so I merely made a syllogism..